# How to I remove repetitive signals in columns in excel, see image

Tags: excel

[image: 20day high, 10 day low]

Hi everyone,
I´m trying to remove the excessive BUY & SELL under the decision column. I want it to look like the image on the right. That is to say I want Blanks after a BUY signal until a SELL signal comes, then print SELL and next columns blanks until a BUY signal.

Are there any function that can speed up the process. I have been doing it manually and it takes a freaking decade.

Comment: If you just need a visual, use conditional formatting to format the font color to white (or the interior color if different) if a cell value is the same as the value in the cell above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with 2 simple formulas, and copy/paste.

In F1 put this formula

```
=E1
```

In F2 put this formula and copy it down by double clicking in the bottom right hand corner of the cell.

```
=IF(E2=E1, "", E2)
```

Once you've done that you can copy column F, select column E and goto Paste Special>Values...